# Как в Ruby разбить целое число на триады?

Tags: ruby

Обращался к англоязычному гуглу, набирая `ruby triad` но он мне выдает картинки с какой-то стриптизершей.

Есть число (Integer), например `146234232`.

Как из него получить строку `"146 234 232"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    def comma_numbers(number, delimiter = ',')
      number.to_s.reverse.gsub(%r{([0-9]{3}(?=([0-9])))}, "\\1#{delimiter}").reverse
   end

number_to_currency(1234567890.506, locale: :fr)
```

Comment: `<число Integer>.to_s.reverse.gsub(/(\d{3}(?=(\d)))/, '\1 ').reverse` - вот так вот

Answer (score 2):

```
i=146234232

i.pr.to_s.pr.split(/(.{1,3})/).pr.arEnd.pr.join(' ').pr


# Данный код выполняется на моем компьютере, 
#   как вы можете видеть на видео.
# У вас этот код возможно не будет выполняться. 
# Так как необходимы дополнительные библиотеки.
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAA-5QZVNEs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
[ 1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345, 123456 ].each do |m|
  puts "%8s\t%8s" % [m, -m].map{ |n|

    n.to_s.reverse.scan(/\d\d?\d?-?/).join(" ").reverse

  }
end

       1          -1
      12         -12
     123        -123
   1 234      -1 234
  12 345     -12 345
 123 456    -123 456
```

Comment: Спасибо, но для отрицательных не работает, и на входе - строка, хотя это не критично.

Comment: @MAXOPKA, добавил `-?` в регексп.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться, например, регулярными выражениями:

```
> 146234232.to_s.gsub(/([0-9]{3})/,'\1 ').strip
=> "146 234 232"
```

Если строка не делится целиком на триады, то последняя группа будет неполной:

```
> 1462342325.to_s.gsub(/([0-9]{3})/,'\1 ').strip
=> "146 234 232 5"
```

Answer (score 1):

Я для разбиения цисла на триады обычно использую регулярное выражение

```
/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 '
```

Answer (score 1):

Так же можно воспользоваться `Enumerable` методами

```
12345.to_s.split("").reverse.each_slice(3).to_a.map{|e| e.reverse.join("")}.reverse.join(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def split(number, delimiter = ' ', group = 3)
    return '0' if number.zero?

    # вычисляем 10 в степени "group", по-умолчанию 1000
    n = 10 ** group; 
    parts = []

    # пока число больше 0, сохраняем остаток деления на n и делим само число на n
    number = number.abs
    while number > 0
        parts.unshift(number % n)
        number = (number / n).floor
    end

    parts.join(delimiter)
end

split(123456789) # "123 456 789"
split(123456789, '-') # "123-456-789"
split(123456789, '-', 2) # "1-23-45-67-89"
```

Comment: А как быть с отрицательными числами?

Comment: @soon, мне кажется это уже будет зависеть от требований: будет ли минус значащим? включать ли его в результат и в каком виде?  Тем не менее самую простую защиту от отрицательных числе добавил (модуль), спасибо.

Comment: Ну и, раз уж на то пошло, на ноль тоже было бы неплохо добавить тест, а то сейчас он пустую строку выдает

Comment: @soon, спасибо, добавил